# Update in realtime

Tags: ios, swift

I want to create an app that will have real time update. It's kind of like a game. Here's what I'm trying to do:

Players will be playing, and as soon as someone gets the highest score, (while he's playing,) it should show it on all devices, and the score should be constantly changing as the high score user is playing.

I know that this is kind of difficult to understand, but I'm basically trying to get a leaderboard like [agars game](http://agar.io/), where the names are constantly changing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with Angularjs and Firebase database. [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the links!! Can you please either show me in detail, or just give a basic outline of how it would be setup? Thanks!

Comment: If you go to the firebase website, it has got everything for you to start with. You can sigup and create an app. Look at this https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/quickstart.html

Comment: Thanks! I checked it up, and it's really helpful! How would I take care of adding new data? Should I add a new one in xcode for every new highscore, or should I add a bunch manually, in the browser, then just replace their values for the highscore?

Comment: All you have to do is create a web application with the Angularjs and firebase js files included. Create an app with firebase and then get the url to add data. If you're looking for ios app, you can use phonegap to convert into mobile compatibility.  Hope this tutorial will help you to get started. http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-web-app-from-scratch-using-angularjs-and-firebase--cms-22391

Comment: Thanks! I got into a problem. I would really appreciate if you can help me out! Again! Thanks!

Comment: That really got me on the right track!! I was totally lost before!